# Django pass list of tuples as url parameter

Tags: django

```
type = [('name1', 'value1'), ('name2', 'value2'), ('name3', 'value')]
```

want to pass above list through url as queryparams. Can not parse it for searching. It returns as string.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search = self.request.GET.get('type')
    # need to convert search as list of tuple
```

Comment: afaik, thats not possible. You can send it as JSON

Answer (score 0):

you did it in wrong way, `get_queryset` method is intended to provide a queryset for the class.
the correct method is `get_context_data`.

```
def get_context_data(self):
    context = super().get_context_dat()
    return context.update({
        "your_tuple_name_in_template": YOUR_TUPLE
         })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    search = self.request.GET.get('type')
    # need to convert search as list of tuple
    search = ast.literal_eval(search)
```

the answer will be list of tuples [('name1', 'value1'), ('name2', 'value2'), ('name3', 'value')]